# Bind the make command to a shortcut

Tags: shortcuts, make, emacs, shortcut-keys

I use `Emacs` under Ubuntu.

I would like to bind the `make` command to a shortcut, so that `makefile` could be launched. If the compilation fails, I would the error message to be shown in a sub-window or the message bar; otherwise, I would all the sub-windows to be closed except the one containing the main text.

Does anyone know how to realize that?

Comment: This isn't off-topic here, but there's a dedicated [emacs.se] site.

Answer (score 0):

The `emacs compile` function is what you want. Type (into Emacs, without the spaces): <kbd>^H f c o m p i l e RETURN</kbd>.